# Make JFrame not repaint

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

im trying not to repaint my window in Java. I have:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);

    }
```

and in main:

```
while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

my JFrame is window and I have tried `window.setIgnoreRepaint(true);` but there was no change. Could you give me a hand? Thank you :)

Comment: You should try overriding paintComponent() instead of paint(Graphics g) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true) {
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

must be replaced with

```
            Timer t=new Timer(10,new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    game.move();
                    game.repaint();
                }
            });
            t.start();
```

And override paintComponent() of content pane.

Answer (score -1):

`super.paint(g)` repaints the window - you need to remove this line.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);

    }
```

Comment: no: a) don't override paint of the frame, instead override paintComponent of its contentPane b) super.paint must be called _always_ except when you wan rather weird effects ;-)